# Having object in XYZ coordinates, how to change Z to X keepeng visual geometry intact?

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry, cgal

So we have an object exported from maya. imagine we have it displayed in XYZ axes. we look at it and it looks as needed. yet we want to see same picture in ZYX. How to make such change to an object?

(example in 2d) we see:

[image]

we need to see:

[image]

while Y shall be kept intact. How to do such thing with [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/packages.html)?

Answer (score 4):

You have to perform a symmetry with respect to the plane `z=x`, which could be easily done swapping `x` and `z` coordinates.

**edit:**

If you have complex structures and swapping coordinate doesn't suffice, you could use [Affine_transformation_3](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Kernel_23_ref/Class_Aff_transformation_3.html) of CGAL.

With the following

```
 Aff_transformation_3<Kernel> t (Kernel::RT m00,
 Kernel::RT m01,
 Kernel::RT m02,
 Kernel::RT m10,
 Kernel::RT m11,
 Kernel::RT m12,
 Kernel::RT m20,
 Kernel::RT m21,
 Kernel::RT m22,
 Kernel::RT hw = RT(1));
```

[image]

inserting the equation of the reflection with respect to the plane `z=x`, you are done.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Reflection_2) you can find the equations for your transformation.

Comment: yeah.. swapping points would be eazy yet we have a 3d object with faces and normals etc. =(

Comment: @myWallJSON didn't it help solving your problem?